# Retrieving distinct records based on a column on Django

Tags: django, distinct

I need to retrieve a list of records for the following table with distinct values in regards to name:

```
Class C:

name                value
A ------------------ 10
A ------------------ 20
A ------------------ 20
B ------------------ 50
C ------------------ 20
D ------------------ 10
B ------------------ 10
A ------------------ 30
```

I need to get rid of all the duplicate values for name and only show the following:

```
name                value
A ------------------ 30
B ------------------ 10
C ------------------ 20
D ------------------ 10
```

As you can see, it almost looks like a python set. I can probably generate the set using Python, but I'm wondering if Django's ORM has this feature.

I tried using distinct, but it doesn't accept any argument to specify which column has to have distinct values. Any idea how to get this query working?

Comment: Do you just want the first value for each name, or what?

Comment: Well you should pick one, because the first and last values are different.  Do you really want arbitrary randomness?

Comment: I actually need the last value. But for this example I put first as I thought there's no difference.

Answer (score 21):

`.distinct()` is the tool, but here's the syntax I had to use :

```
Model.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
```

This way you only get a list [A,B,C,D] of values, not the objects themseleves.

Comment: This will work only with PostgreSQL. If u are using MySQL or SQLite, u're out of luck.

Comment: @SerafimS. This works in MySQL and SQLite.  Doing *distinct on* doesn't work PostgreSQL, but the query in this answer does not do a distinct on!

Answer (score 2):

Problem with sqlite distinct is it distincts on all returned values. To distinct on one column name, for example: 'url' to get all unique urls from a table, but also get the rest of the data, use a subquery.

The subquery gets the IDs of the url's and then uses that to do another query on those ideas. This is not as quick as a regular distinct of course.

```
link_ids = (
    Resources
    .values('url')
    .distinct()
    .annotate(
        occurrences=Count('url'),  # make unique 'urls' only occur once.
        pk=Min('pk')  # return pk of first occurrence
    )
)
broken_links_qs = (
    Resources.filter(id__in=Subquery(link_ids.values('pk')))
)
```

(At the time the previous answers where given, django did not have Subquery functionality yet.)

Comment: Where do I should include Count and Min from?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't super elegant but it gets the job done in about one line:

```
# Fetch all rows to limit num of queries
all_rows = MyModel.objects.all()

# Query against the full list to return a list of objects
item_list = [all_rows.filter(myfield=item['myfield']).last() for item in MyModel.objects.values('myfield').distinct()]
```

This retrieves the full model instance for each of the values you're doing the DISTINCT on.  Some use cases might need different filtering.

Then just use the `name` and `value` properties in each item on `item_list` to get your distinct data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use raw like:

`queryraw = C.objects.raw('SELECT name, value FROM prj_c GROUP BY name')`

or add an ORDER BY to have the higher value for any group:

`queryraw = C.objects.raw('SELECT name, value FROM prj_c GROUP BY name ORDER BY value')`

In any case you can have `list()` of objects.

Usefull documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 0):

Using the following syntax should solve your problem.
values('name', 'value').distinct()